# Regular expression for URL doesnt work if there is a colon in the final part

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that looks for web site addresses in a piece of text.  This is working fine unless there is a colon in the final part of the address.

It works for the following for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-a-question and the whole address is included.

However 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask:a-question 
stops at the colon and "a-question" is not included.

The regular expression I am using just now is

```
((https?:\\/\\/([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(\\/([\\w/_\\-\\.\\?\\=\\%\\&]*(\\?\\s{1})?)?)?)?)(?<!\\.)
```

I also tried the following regex and it did the same as above.

```
 (((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?))|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}
```

Any help would be brilliant, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/4Lt

Comment: this work for php, but by our example u have to add an extra '\' to work for the language that you are using

Comment: This didn't seem to work but i did manage to fix it.  I changed the regex to include "\\:".  Thanks for the comment. **